# Displaying data using checkboxes for specific values when checked

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to display data from mysql with multiple true(1) or false(0) values but can't identify a way to display them using checkbox type. I want to display results where the result will be true for multiple categories when there checkbox is selected.

I'm assuming the php will something along the lines of
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE $checkbox,$checkbox='1'`
with a sort of array or i could be horribly wrong.

Comment: Horribly wrong I am afraid

Comment: Have you first worked out that a form will not send a value for a checkbox if the checkbox is not checked?

Comment: For a start the where clause should not have PHP `$variables` in it. It would be a great help if you showed us more of the HTML and PHP that you are actually using

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3"  
<?php if(array_value->getCheckbox()){checked} ?> > your text <br>
```

Maybe once you got your array of eg. categories with field checkbox field set to true or false. You can display checkboxes and add attribute "cheked" if ever the value is true